# How to make links wrap or scroll in a col element in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a row element containing two columns. Currently, my first column sometimes extends over my second column because the `problem.problem_description` part contains a really long link that extends really far. I'm trying to make it so that **really long links wrap or can be scrolled across**. If the `problem.name` is too long, it wraps the name because it's multiple words (which is ideal behavior).

I'm using bootstrap and currently my code looks as follows, any ideas?

```
<div *ngFor = "let element of elements" class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4 border">
      <b>{{element.name}}</b>
      <p *ngFor = "let problem of element.problems" class="border">
         <b><u>Problem Name:</u></b> {{problem.name}}<br>
         <u>Problem Description:</u> {{problem.problem_description}}<br>
      </p>
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-4 border">
      <button>View Similar Problems</button>
      <p class="border">
         //... added stuff
      </p>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this by adding to the css file. I just added

```
.border {
   overflow-y: scroll;
}
```